# How do I get the ListIterator to work properly?

Tags: java

I am trying to iterate a LinkedList of words entered by a user using a TextField on an Applet and return the number of times a word is found in the list.

The code prints that no words have been found in the list on every occasion even with words that the user has added to the list. I think the problem is with the expression I have in my Iterator or with my add word to list button because I also think that words possibly aren't actually being added to the list.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class Applet2 extends JApplet {

    private String text;
    private int text1;
    JTextField value1, value2;
    LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
    public JLabel jLabel;
    public int count = 0;
    public int search_count = 0;

    public void init() {

        JLabel prompt = new JLabel("Please enter a word");
        JLabel prompt1 = new JLabel("Please enter a certain letter");

        value1 = new JTextField(10);
        value2 = new JTextField(10);

        JPanel textPanel = new JPanel();
        textPanel.add(prompt);
        textPanel.add(value1);
        add(textPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        textPanel.add(prompt1);
        textPanel.add(value2);


        JPanel centrePanel = new JPanel();
        text = "";
        jLabel = new JLabel(text);
        centrePanel.add(jLabel);
        add(centrePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        JButton but = new JButton("Add word");
        JButton but1 = new JButton("Clear");
        JButton but2 = new JButton("Remove first occurrence");
        JButton but3 = new JButton("Remove all occurrences");
        JButton but4 = new JButton("Display all words begging with certain letter");
        JButton but5 = new JButton("Search");

        JPanel butPanel = new JPanel();

        butPanel.add(but);
        butPanel.add(but1);
        butPanel.add(but5);
        butPanel.add(but2);
        butPanel.add(but3);
        butPanel.add(but4);


        add(butPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        but.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler(this));
        but1.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler1(this));
        but5.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler2(this));
        //but2.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler3(this));


    }

    class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

        private Applet2 theApplet;

        public ButtonHandler(Applet2 app) {
            theApplet = app;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            text = theApplet.value1.getText();

            try {

                text1 = Integer.parseInt(text);
                jLabel.setText("ERROR - The string " + "'" + text1 + "'" + " is not a valid word");

            } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {

                if (text.length() != 0) {
                    jLabel.setText("Word " + "'" + text + "'" + " has been added to the list");
                    count = count + 1;
                } else {
                    jLabel.setText("ERROR - Please enter a word");
                }

            }

        }
    }

    class ButtonHandler1 implements ActionListener {

        private Applet2 theApplet;

        public ButtonHandler1(Applet2 app) {
            theApplet = app;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            list.clear();
            jLabel.setText("List has been cleared");
            count = 0;

        }
    }

    class ButtonHandler2 implements ActionListener {

        private Applet2 theApplet;

        public ButtonHandler2(Applet2 app) {
            theApplet = app;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String text = theApplet.value1.getText();
```

This is where I am trying to iterate through the LinkedList.

```
            ListIterator<String> listIterator = list.listIterator();



            while (listIterator.hasNext()) {
```

I think the problem is with this condition here because I am sure that I have implemented the count variable correctly.

```
                    if (text.equals(listIterator.next())) {

                        search_count = search_count + 1;
                    }
                }
```

Here is where I am trying to print out onto the Applet how many times the word was found. The code prints out that no words have been added on every occasion.

```
                jLabel.setText("Word " + "'" + text + "'" + " was found " + search_count + " time(s) in the list");



        if (text.length() == 0) {

                jLabel.setText("Please enter a word - The total number of words in the list are: " + count);

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The code you posted calls two methods on the list: clear() and listIterator(). So you never add anything to the list.

Comment: Can you please explain, I've tried to add the functionality to clear the list on the clear button which is what I think I've done. I am trying to get my Iterator to find all the user inputted words in the list

Comment: I have explained. The action listener for the "Add" button doesn't add anything to the list.

Comment: how do I make it add something to the list?

Comment: By calling `list.add()`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28E%29